# does modifying /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf always require reboot?

Tags: modprobe

I have the following two files

- `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

  - contains `blacklist usb-storage`
- `/etc/modprobe.d/usb-storage.conf`

  - contains `install usb-storage /bin/true`

When in effect, I cannot connect a usb dvd reader to my Linux server (RHEL-7.9).  When I need to, I have to comment out the *usb-storage* line in each of the two conf files, and then reboot.  I hate having to reboot.  Is there a command that I can run after I comment out those two items that will allow the operating system to recognize an attached usb storage device, without having to reboot?

Comment: Does `sudo modprobe usb-storage` do it?

Comment: I don't know, will try it in a few.

Comment: so it works but when I try to go back to disallowing usb storage it keeps allowing until a reboot where the modprobe statements are not commented out

Answer (score 4):

When you want to load the `usb-storage` module, there’s no need to even modify your configuration files, let alone reboot. Leave your `modprobe` directives uncommented, so that they are applied. When you want to access your DVD reader, don’t modify your configuration files; instead, run `modprobe` and tell it to ignore `install` directives:

```
sudo modprobe -i usb-storage
```

When you’re finished, disconnect your DVD reader and remove the module:

```
sudo rmmod usb-storage
```